# Codeigniter button redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

I just want to ask because I'm working on Codeigniter and I'm have a button in home page wherein if click, it will page redirect to registration page.

```
<input type='button' onClick='<?php redirect(base_url() . 'register/index'); ?>' />
```

I also tried the form helper.

```
<body>
    <?php
        $data = array('register' => array('name'    => 'register',
            'id'        => 'register',
            'value' => 'TRUE',
            'type'  => 'button',
            'content' => 'Register',
            'onClick'   => redirect(base_url() . 'register/index')
       );
    ?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo form_button(element('register', $data, )); ?></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</body>
```

The problem is nothing happens when I try to click the button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CodeIgniter's redirect() function means to make a [HTTP 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) response, which only works before content being outputted. It's designed for controller and should never appear in your views.

Navigation in browser-side can be implemented by Javascript:

```
<button onclick="location.href='<?php echo base_url();?>register/index'">Register</button>
```

Comment: Your browser didn't navigate?

Comment: May I know how can I do this using codeigniter's form_button?

Comment: 'onClick' => 'location.href="'. base_url() .'register/index"'

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the CI form helper you have use it like this:

```
echo form_button('name','content');

// Would produce
// <button name="name" type="button">Content</button>
```

Or you can pass an associative array containing any data you wish your form to contain:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'button',
    'id' => 'button',
    'value' => 'true',
    'type' => 'reset',
    'content' => 'Reset'
);

echo form_button($data);

// Would produce:
// <button name="button" id="button" value="true" type="reset">Reset</button>
```

If you would like your form to contain some additional data, like JavaScript, you can pass it as a string in the third parameter:

```
$js = 'onClick="some_function()"';

echo form_button('mybutton', 'Click Me', $js);
```

And make sure that the helper is loaded:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a common javascript function for your project if you need and can call it like below :

```
<button onClick="return redirect('<?php echo base_url();?>register/index');">Register</button>
```

and javascript function is as below:

```
<script>
function redirect(url){
window.location.href = url;
return false;
}
</script>
```

OR 
you could simply do the following

```
<button onClick="window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url();?>register/index';return false;">Register</button>
```

Please remember to return false so that the default event of button click is ignored.

Comment: How can I do this using form_button? I just want to utilize the codeigniter.